# Sum over squared index

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Is there any way to compute the finite series

$$S_M = \sum_{n=1}^{M} r^{n^2}, $$

for some real $r$, integer $M$?

Comment: (a) Do you mean a "closed" formula?
(b) Why do you want a "closed" formula? What is the motivation?

Comment: A closed-form expression would be the best case scenario. However, I'd be interested in any techniques for expressing this series in terms of better known ones. I have no real motivation aside from curiosity.

Comment: Usually, finite sums count as closed form.